# Как правильно сформировать ответ XML-RPC Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Есть метод get. 
Он принимает id пользователя. 
В ответ нужно отправить массив сообщений, которые есть для этого пользователя и количество.
Вот такие данные нужно передать:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) {
["messages"]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> array(5) {
        ["MessageId"]=> "1"
    ["ToUserId"]=> "1"
    ["FromUserId"]=> "3"
    ["MessageText"]=> "my text"
    ["MessageDate"]=> "2015-09-06 12:40:16"
  }
  [1]=> array(5) {
        ["MessageId"]=> "2"
    ["ToUserId"]=> "1"
    ["FromUserId"]=> "3"
    ["MessageText"]=> "any message"
    ["MessageDate"]=> "2015-09-06 12:41:37"
  }
}
["count"]=> 2}}
```

Как все это правильно передать с помощью xml-rpc?

Использую Codeigniter.

```
public function get($request)
{
    $params = $request->output_parameters();
    $toUserId = (int)$params[0]["UserId"];

    $query = $this->db->get_where( 'messages', array('ToUserId' => $toUserId) );

    if( count($query->result_array()) > 0 )
    {
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $response = array(
            array(
                'messages' => $result,
                'count'    => count($result)
            ),
            'struct'
        );
        return $this->xmlrpc->send_response($response);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->xmlrpc->send_error_message('404', 'No messages.');
    }
}
```

НЕ работает. Потому как в **$result** хранится массив, в котором в свою очередь есть массивы.

Пробовал вместо 'struct' использовать 'array', не получается никак.

С кодом, который выше получаю ошибку:

Severity: Warning

Message:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Filename: libraries/Xmlrpc.php

Line Number: 455

Подскажите, как передать двухмерный массив?

**UPDATE.**

Вот код из документации CideIgniter:

```
$response = array(
             array(
                    'flerror' => array(FALSE, 'boolean'),
                    'message' => "Thanks for the ping!")
                 )
             'struct');
```

return $this->xmlrpc->send_response($response);

У меня все похоже, как исключением одного момента.
'flerror' это массив. А у меня это массив массивов. Как я понимаю, так делать нельзя, потому как возникает ошибка парсинга переданных мною данных.

Comment: *в $result хранится массив, в котором в свою очередь есть массивы.* - так и в ["messages"]=> array(2) тоже самое. Если структуры не совпадают, покажите их обе. А вообще-то, `array( 'messages' => $result,` работает дл многомерных массивов

Comment: Исправил вопрос, написал ошибку, которую я получаю.

Comment: И какая ж строка 455-я?

Comment: if ( ! isset($value[1], $this->xmlrpcTypes[$value[1]]))

Comment: Вот этот файл: [ссылка](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Xmlrpc.php)

Comment: то есть это где-то  совсем в другом месте?

Comment: Да, именно. Как я понимаю, я просто передаю не верные данные в функцию send_response($response). Ошибка возникает на этапе парсинга переданных мною данных, как я понял.

Comment: вы лучше сделайте var_dump вашего массива перед передачей куда-то. и сравните структуру с той, что должна быть. если сами не справитесь, выложите  их обе. попробуем помочь

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: var_dump моего массива есть в самом начале вопроса.

Comment: Из документации: "Как и запрос, ответ должен быть оформлен в виде массива.. Но ответный массив должен содержать только одно значение . Это значение может быть массивом с субмассивами, но должно иметь только один индекс.. Иначе говоря, структура ответа должна быть такой: [ссылка](http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html) (раздел "Форма ответа")"

Comment: `$response = array('Response data', 'array');` А если вместо 'Response data' подставить ваш массив? У вас сейчас не так

Comment: Да, не так. Уже разобрался. Сейчас напишу что получилось. Но как-то очень запутано вышло. Хотелось бы услышать подсказки как улучшить это все...

Comment: Не очень понимаю, почему вы пишете, что запутано. Кажется, все очень понятно

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил.

Вот код:

```
public function get($request)
{
    $params = $request->output_parameters();
    $toUserId = (int)$params[0]["UserId"];

    $query = $this->db->get_where( 'messages', array('ToUserId' => $toUserId) );

    if( count($query->result_array()) > 0 )
    {
        $result = $query->result_array();

        $result_arr = array();

        foreach($result as $item)
        {
            array_push($result_arr, array($item, 'struct'));
        }

        $response = array(
            array(
                'messages' => array($result_arr, 'array'),
                'count'    => count($result_arr)
            ),
            'struct'
        );

        return $this->xmlrpc->send_response($response);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->xmlrpc->send_error_message('404', 'No messages.');
    }
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы каждый массив состоял из 2 элементов: данные (тоже может быть массивом и тип). [см. документацию](http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html)